# Can I restore a Titanium backup from an Incredible to a Captivate?

Tags: restore, titanium-backup

I had an HTC Incredible that I backed up with Titanium Backup Pro. I just got a Samsung Galaxy Captivate and wish to restore the backup, but when I go to restore, the app doesn't find the backup on the SD card. I went into the SD card and confirmed the backup is there.

Is it possible that I can't restore from an HTC phone to a Samsung one? If so, can I at least restore the apps on the SD card?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

May be the app is not recognizing the location of the backup. Do the following and see if that works

1. Remove all the backup files from the new Samsung Captivate
2. Now, from Captivate do a Titanium backup, it will create a backup folder with backed up apps.
3. Then, copy all old backup files from HTC to that location.
4. Try titanium backup again, this might show all the backed up apps now.

Hope that works. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hossain is actually correct, but you don't need to go through that process to find the location.

The Captivate has internal SD storage separate from the main phone storage and the external SD card.  As such, the external SD card is mounted at `/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/` rather than just `/mnt/sdcard/`.  So you just need to copy the `TitaniumBackup` folder from that first path to the second, since that is where Titanium is looking. **Edit** or, as Saiboogu notes below, you can change the directory used by TB.

When you move apps to SD they go on the external SD card, but almost everything else uses the internal SD.  You'll find that photos, downloaded files, and so on go there.

Comment: Rather than add a 3rd answer reiterating most of the same info, I'll just make a suggestion here - Instead of copying the backup to the internal (and risk loosing backups if the device is bricked or otherwise broken) you can go to Preferences in TB, and change the "Backup folder location" to the external SD. Recent versions of TB even have an autodetect option in the folder chooser. If I recall right you have to navigate up to the / file system before autodetect will search external storage.

Comment: @Saiboogu I meant "copy" in the "make a copy" sense, not the "move" sense. Having two copies in separate places is probably even safer than changing TB's folder setting :)

Comment: True, if you make the copy daily. Since I'm too lazy to do that, I just set TB to backup by default to my SD card, so in a worst-case scenario I can just pop the card into a new phone and be all set. :) Also and unrelated - how come it keeps dropping my reference to your name? Weird.

Comment: @Saiboogu Oh yeah, I just meant for the initial sync, I see what you mean now. I've softbricked my device a couple times and only lost the internal SD data once, but I guess once is enough :P.  Though lots of people have external SD problems with Samsungs as well. Anyways.  It drops my name because the post owner always gets notified and there are no other commenters, so it's redundant.

Comment: I've also had one softbrick that killed the internal SD, and like you said - once is enough. ;) Makes sense about the notifications too, thanks for the explanation.